# Is it possible to statically check pattern matching exhaustiveness for Python dataclasses?

Tags: python, mypy, python-dataclasses

Let suppose we have several dataclasses with the only parent (ABC-class). Next, we have some function which process each case individually via pattern matching:

```py
from abc import ABC
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class Token(ABC):
    pass


@dataclass
class PlusToken(Token):
    pass


@dataclass
class DigitToken(Token):
    digit: int


def pretty_print(token: Token) -> str:
    match token:
        case PlusToken():
            return 'PLUS <+>'
        case DigitToken(digit=digit):
            return f'DIGIT <{digit}>'
```

So, I want to statically check (using mypy) that pattern matching in `pretty_print` is exhaustive, i.e. no case was forgotten.

For `Enum` or for `Union`-type I use `assert_never` from `typing` in `case _:` branch, but it does not work for dataclasses:

```py
def pretty_print(token: Token) -> str:
    match token:
        ...  # PlusToken, DigitToken cases
        case _:
            assert_never(token)  #  Argument 1 to "assert_never" has incompatible type "Token"; expected "NoReturn"  [arg-type]
```

I suppose it is related that it is possible to create `Token`-instance like as every `ABC` in Python. But maybe there is another way to check the exhaustiveness of pattern matching? Thanks in advance!

**My environment**

1. Python 3.11.2
2. mypy 1.3.0

Comment: Related section from the Python typing docs: [Marking Code as Unreachable](https://typing.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/unreachable.html#marking-code-as-unreachable). In particular, the line "If we used assert_never() in the lowest_unused() function, the type checker would produce an error, _because the type checker cannot prove_ that the line is unreachable."

Comment: I am doubtful that it is possible to come closer with static checking. There's no limit on many many other `Token` subclasses may exist outside your module, so I don't think type checkers can check for exhaustiveness. If mypy had a feature to mark `Token` as "closed" (i.e., the only subclasses that exists are the ones in this module), then maybe, but I don't think it offers such a feature

Comment: You could perhaps create a `Literal` of all the valid `Token` subclasses, which mypy can check for exhaustiveness. That would at least help protect against some `match`s being exhaustive while others are not. But that only moves the exhaustiveness problem to a different part of the code, and would make the `match` more awkward.

Comment: The problem is the `token: Token` type is open-ended, you need a type with a fixed number of members to be able to do exhaustiveness checking. But you are trying to solve the wrong problem, you should move the `pretty_print` to be a method on the dataclasses.

Comment: ...there's probably a good case for defining this as `__str__` method on the class, then when you use builtin `print` func on an instance of Token that's what you will see (or `s = str(instance)` to get value into a variable)

Comment: An alternative solution here would be to put an abstract print() method within the `Token` base class, and then require each subclass to define that method.
Then your `pretty_print(token: Token)` function would just call `token.print()` and its not possible to miss any cases.  
Or get rid of pretty_print() entirely and just make the behavior you want the `__str__` of each token type.  (and just noticed I hadn't refreshed the page in 2 hours and didn't see Arentropics comments until after I posted)

Comment: Thanks! I got the solution about creating a method in `Token`-class, and I did this thing. But I do not really like this solution (but maybe it is absolutely ok), because the rendering logic is a part of the token-object. For example, I need to render my token many ways: as plain string, as Markdown, as HTML, etc. and then I have to create a new method for any of them. I think the better solution is an abstract `Foramtter` class with abstract method `format` that get a token and render it, because we separate token data and its formatting. But maybe I am wrong.

Comment: Solution with object-level methods (not `__str__` if you need several options, because it'd be ambiguous) looks saner to me. You may want to add a `__format__` method with specifiers for every sort of formatting that you need, or just several methods like `to_html` and `to_markdown`. It's really a Token's responsibility - no matter where, it's formatted some way to HTML or Markdown, and also it makes adding new tokens much easier. Using ABC helps to enforce implementation for every Token subclass.